# attaching information to a form in its GET request

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using this code inside my template to attach info to a GET request

```
"{% url 'foo_create'%}?fooHolder_pk={{fooHolder.pk}}"
```

and I have a form. now I want to use fooHolder.pk to attach it as a Foreign key to foo in the form GET request. But when I do that. The POST request still shows that the foreign key is null.

Note: I am using function Based Views

The view

```py
def foo_create(request):
    data = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = fooForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            foos = foo.objects.all()
            data['html_foo_list'] = render_to_string('app1/includes/partial_foo_list.html',{'foos':foos})
        else:
            # print(form.errors)
            data['form_is_valid'] = False


    else:
        fooHolder_pk = int(request.GET['fooHolder_pk'])
        form = fooForm()
        form.fooHolder = fooHolder.objects.get(id = fooHolder_pk) 
        form.save(commit=False)


    context = {'form':form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('app1/includes/partial_foo_create.html', context, request=request)

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: you're confusing things here. Are you submitting the form with POST or GET? That's the HTTP method of your request. Now, you can POST a form and still add **query parameters** to the url. Your Django view will be able to retrieve those from the `GET` dictionary of your request (even though the request method is POST).

Comment: So please show your view. And show the `<form>` tag in your template.

Comment: I am using a get request to retrieve the empty form. and then Post request in the same view to post the information. I get query parameters in the get request and I want to use it to retrieve an object and attach it as a foreign key to foo in either the get or post request but I want that before saving the form.

Comment: show us your views.

Comment: Then why not just add a field in your form to handle the FK that you want to pass?

Comment: I added the view

Comment: what does your view return? there's no response

Comment: anyway, inside `if method == 'POST'` you can also get `request.GET.get('fooHolder_pk')` if it's a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass `form` to your template, you should use `{{ form.fooHolder.pk }}` in the action URL for the form.

Also, inside your `POST` handler, you can just still use `request.GET.get('fooHolder')` as the `GET` dictionary always holds all the **query parameters** regardless of the HTTP method used.